# How to save a multiple django forms into a database in a good way? Enhance Performance

Tags: mysql, database, django, forms

I want to save multiple django forms into a database in a good way, because it takes very long time to save these forms on a server.
the forms is related to each other, so I am using a serial saving technique "one form by one".
How can I maintain my forms to save quickly to database.

Forms Code:

```
    employee_main=EmployeesForm(request.POST)
    employee_administrative=EmployeesAdminstrativeForm(request.POST)
    employee_stay=EmployeesStayForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
    employee_dependents=EmployeesDependentsForm(request.POST,request.FILES,prefix="u")
    employee_insurance=EmployeesInssuranceForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
    employee_security=EmployeesSecurityForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
    if employee_main.is_valid() and employee_administrative.is_valid() and employee_stay.is_valid() and employee_dependents.is_valid() and employee_insurance.is_valid() and employee_security.is_valid():
        emp=employee_main.save(commit=False)

        emp.save()

        emp_ad=employee_administrative.save(commit=False)
        emp_ad.employee_id=emp.id
        emp_ad.save()

        jobtitle_code=JobTitle.objects.get(id=emp_ad.jobtitle_id).Code
        Employees.objects.filter(id=emp.id).update(Code=jobtitle_code +"-"+ str(emp_ad.employee_id+25))

        Employees.objects.filter(id=emp_ad.moder_id).update(ismodeer=True)

        emp_s=employee_stay.save(commit=False)
        emp_s.employee_id=emp.id
        emp_s.save()
        emp_dd=employee_dependents.save(commit=False)
        emp_dd.employee_id=emp.id
        emp_dd.save()
        emp_ss=employee_insurance.save(commit=False)
        emp_ss.employee_id=emp.id
        emp_ss.save()
        from authentication.models import users
        user=users(employee_id=emp.id,UserName=request.POST["UserName"],Password=request.POST["Password"],isadmin=0)
        user.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/employees/all_employees/")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Put all the above code in a [transaction](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/).
2. Make `Employee` inherit `User`. Read more about [model inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance) in Django.
3. You create the `Employee` object, then you update it using `Employees.objects.filter(id=emp.id).update(Code=...)`. Just modify the code before the first save
4. [django-modelcluster](https://github.com/torchbox/django-modelcluster) may help you. It's worth a try.